# zig creating a C library

Tags: zig

**Closed** - see the end of the entry

I want to make a C callable library using the zig language.
I decided to start with the two examples in the Zig documentation. "Exporting a C Library" and "Mixing Object Files".
In each case I copied the three relevant files(from 0.6.0 docs).

- A C file called test.c,
- a zig file called respectively mathtest.zig (for the Exporting a C Library example) and base64.zig (for the Mixing Object Files example), and
- a build.zig file.

Both examples fail to build.

The Exporting a C Library example fails to compile test.c with a message  cannot find mathtest.h

The Mixing Object Files example fails to compile test.c with cannot find base64.h

Here are the three files for the Exporting C Libary example:

**mathtest.zig**

```
export fn add(a: i32, b: i32) i32 {
    return a + b;
}
```

**test.c**

```
// This header is generated by zig from mathtest.zig
#include "mathtest.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int32_t result = add(42, 1337);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

**build.zig**

```
const Builder = @import("std").build.Builder;

pub fn build(b: *Builder) void {
    const lib = b.addSharedLibrary("mathtest", "mathtest.zig", b.version(1, 0, 0));

    const exe = b.addExecutable("test", null);
    exe.addCSourceFile("test.c", &[_][]const u8{"-std=c99"});
    exe.linkLibrary(lib);
    exe.linkSystemLibrary("c");

    b.default_step.dependOn(&exe.step);

    const run_cmd = exe.run();

    const test_step = b.step("test", "Test the program");
    test_step.dependOn(&run_cmd.step);
}
```

**Part of the error message**

```
~/Projects/zig/z-c-lib $ zig build test
/home/robert/Projects/zig/z-c-lib/test.c:2:10: fatal error: 'mathtest.h' file not found
#include "mathtest.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

The following command failed:
/home/robert/zig/zig clang -c -nostdinc -fno-spell-checking -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -isystem /home/robert/zig/lib/zig/include -isystem /home/robert/zig/lib/zig/libc/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -isystem /home/robert/zig/lib/zig/libc/include/generic-glibc -isystem /home/robert/zig/lib/zig/libc/include/x86_64-linux-any -isystem /home/robert/zig/lib/zig/libc/include/any-linux-any -Xclang -target-cpu -Xclang znver2 -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang -3dnow -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang -3dnowa -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang +64bit -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang +adx -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang +aes -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang +avx -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang +avx2 -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang -avx512bf16 -Xclang -target-feature -Xclang -avx512b
```

I cannot find a file named `mathtest.h` on my system so I assume it was not generated, contrary to the claim in the test.c file.

What am I missing ? Help gratefully accepted.

**Answers and More questions**

I discovered the `-femit-h` options:

```
zig build-lib mathtest.zig -femit-h
```

will create a `mathtest.h` file and then

```
zig build
```

will be successful.

I further discovered that
these lines in the `build.zig` files

```
const lib = b.addSharedLibrary('mathtest', 'mathtest.zig', b.version(1, 0, 0));
lib.femit_h = true;
```

will ensure that

```
zig build test
```

will be successful and generate the answer 1379 as indicated in the docs.

BUT - this mod to the build.zig file does not leave a `mathtest.h` file around after it runs.

That seems to be the final hurdle to generating a usable C library from a Zig code.

**Final piece in the puzzle**

If I add

```
lib.setOutputDir("build");
```

to the `build.zig` file. The `mathtest.h` and `libmathtest.a` (or .so) files will be saved into a `build` dir.

**Call this one close**

Comment: For future readers, the `-femit-h` was removed at the time of writing (tested in `zig version 0.8.0`). It's not ready yet but planned.

Comment: As of zig version 0.11.0, `-femit-h` option is available, although the zig 0.11.0 documentation doesn't mention the option.

Answer (score 6):

Ok so part of the answer is simple, but maybe obscure, the -femit-h options.
The command

```
zig build-lib mathtest.zig -femit-h
```

will generate a `mathtest.h` file.
But how do I add that options to the

```
const lib = b.addSharedLibrary("mathtest", "mathtest.zig", b.version(1, 0, 0));
```

line in the build.zig file.

Comment: That's `-femit-h`, not `-femti-h`